# write 8 bites to RS-485 using modbus_tk

Tags: python, modbus

Ethernet to RS-485 сonverter is connected to the computer and then I have 3 RS-485 controllers connected. I am writing registers to controllers using **pymodbus**. How can I do the same with **modbus_tk**?

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
from pymodbus.utilities import computeCRC

Defaults.Timeout = 0.02
client = ModbusClient('192.168.0.191', port=9761)
client.connect()

builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder()
data = [0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF]
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[0])
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[1])
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[2])
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[3])
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[4])
builder.add_8bit_uint(data[5])
crc = computeCRC(data)
builder.add_8bit_uint(crc >> 8)
builder.add_8bit_uint(crc & 0x00FF)
payload = builder.build()
address = 0
client.write_registers(address, payload, skip_encode=True, unit=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show what you have tried so far with modbus_tk? With https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/tcpmaster_example.py you could make a start?

Comment: I've tried to send bytes using `master.execute(...)` but I don't understand how to indicate that I want to transfer exactly 8 bytes and where to specify these 8 bytes. I couldn't find such examples anywhere...